# Filter into 2nd degree list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

i have a `list` named `info` that contains a multiple **lists**

the structure of `info` is : `info=[[time, city, time, number]]`

here an example of `info` :

```
info = [
[0, 'alger', 'en stationnement', '1132'],
[1620, 'Place du 1er Mai', '0:27:00', '1002'],
[1800, 'Vieux Kouba', '0:30:00', '1134'],
[3420, 'garidi', '0:57:00', '1004'],
[3600, 'Vieux Kouba', '1:00:00', '1136'],
[5220, 'Place du 1er Mai', '1:27:00', '1006'],
[6000, 'alger', '1:40:00', '1132'],
[7620, 'Place du 1er Mai', '2:07:00', '1002'],
[7800, 'Vieux Kouba', '2:10:00', '1134'],
[9420, 'Hamma', '2:37:00', '1004'],
[9600, 'Vieux Kouba', '2:40:00', '1136'],
[11220, 'Hamma', '3:07:00', '1006'],
[12000, 'alger', '3:20:00', '1132'],
[13800, 'Vieux Kouba', '3:50:00', '1134'],
]
```

i want the list to not contain more than 2 item of each city.

like for the `city` **alger** there are **3** items, the **filtred** list must **contain** only **the first 2 item**

Comment: What have you tried until now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `collections.defaultdict` to keep count

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

c = defaultdict(int)

result = []
for i in info:
    if c[i[1]] == 2:
        continue
    c[i[1]] += 1
    result.append(i)
    
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 'alger', 'en stationnement', '1132'],
 [1620, 'Place du 1er Mai', '0:27:00', '1002'],
 [1800, 'Vieux Kouba', '0:30:00', '1134'],
 [3420, 'garidi', '0:57:00', '1004'],
 [3600, 'Vieux Kouba', '1:00:00', '1136'],
 [5220, 'Place du 1er Mai', '1:27:00', '1006'],
 [6000, 'alger', '1:40:00', '1132'],
 [9420, 'Hamma', '2:37:00', '1004'],
 [11220, 'Hamma', '3:07:00', '1006']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
info = [
[0, 'alger', 'en stationnement', '1132'],
[1620, 'Place du 1er Mai', '0:27:00', '1002'],
[1800, 'Vieux Kouba', '0:30:00', '1134'],
[3420, 'garidi', '0:57:00', '1004'],
[3600, 'Vieux Kouba', '1:00:00', '1136'],
[5220, 'Place du 1er Mai', '1:27:00', '1006'],
[6000, 'alger', '1:40:00', '1132'],
[7620, 'Place du 1er Mai', '2:07:00', '1002'],
[7800, 'Vieux Kouba', '2:10:00', '1134'],
[9420, 'Hamma', '2:37:00', '1004'],
[9600, 'Vieux Kouba', '2:40:00', '1136'],
[11220, 'Hamma', '3:07:00', '1006'],
[12000, 'alger', '3:20:00', '1132'],
[13800, 'Vieux Kouba', '3:50:00', '1134'],
]

tmp = {}
for item in info:
    tmp.setdefault(item[1], []).append(item)

out = []
for item in tmp.values():
    out.extend(item[:2])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[0, 'alger', 'en stationnement', '1132'],
 [6000, 'alger', '1:40:00', '1132'],
 [1620, 'Place du 1er Mai', '0:27:00', '1002'],
 [5220, 'Place du 1er Mai', '1:27:00', '1006'],
 [1800, 'Vieux Kouba', '0:30:00', '1134'],
 [3600, 'Vieux Kouba', '1:00:00', '1136'],
 [3420, 'garidi', '0:57:00', '1004'],
 [9420, 'Hamma', '2:37:00', '1004'],
 [11220, 'Hamma', '3:07:00', '1006']]
```

Answer (score 0):

below

```
from collections import defaultdict 
info = [
[0, 'alger', 'en stationnement', '1132'],
[1620, 'Place du 1er Mai', '0:27:00', '1002'],
[1800, 'Vieux Kouba', '0:30:00', '1134'],
[3420, 'garidi', '0:57:00', '1004'],
[3600, 'Vieux Kouba', '1:00:00', '1136'],
[5220, 'Place du 1er Mai', '1:27:00', '1006'],
[6000, 'alger', '1:40:00', '1132'],
[7620, 'Place du 1er Mai', '2:07:00', '1002'],
[7800, 'Vieux Kouba', '2:10:00', '1134'],
[9420, 'Hamma', '2:37:00', '1004'],
[9600, 'Vieux Kouba', '2:40:00', '1136'],
[11220, 'Hamma', '3:07:00', '1006'],
[12000, 'alger', '3:20:00', '1132'],
[13800, 'Vieux Kouba', '3:50:00', '1134'],
]
d = defaultdict(lambda :0)
new_info = []
for item in info:
  if d[item[1]] >= 2:
    continue
  else:
    d[item[1]] += 1
    new_info.append(item)
for item in new_info: 
  print(item)
```

output

```
[0, 'alger', 'en stationnement', '1132']
[1620, 'Place du 1er Mai', '0:27:00', '1002']
[1800, 'Vieux Kouba', '0:30:00', '1134']
[3420, 'garidi', '0:57:00', '1004']
[3600, 'Vieux Kouba', '1:00:00', '1136']
[5220, 'Place du 1er Mai', '1:27:00', '1006']
[6000, 'alger', '1:40:00', '1132']
[9420, 'Hamma', '2:37:00', '1004']
[11220, 'Hamma', '3:07:00', '1006']
```